# Unhandled exception - Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to flutter and learning through a tutorial about notodo_app on youtube. so I was following the same codes and already tried rewriting almost everything but when I started working with the initstate, setstate.

**Code related to setstate**

```
final List<NoDoItem> _itemList = <NoDoItem>[];

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 _readNoDoList();
}


void _handleSubmitted(String text) async {
 _textEditingController.clear();

 NoDoItem noDoItem = NoDoItem(text, DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
 int savedItemId = await db.saveItem(noDoItem);
 NoDoItem addedItem = await db.getItem(savedItemId);
 setState(() {
  _itemList.insert(0, addedItem); 
 });
 print("Item saved id: $savedItemId");
}

_readNoDoList() async {
 List items = await db.getItems();
 items.forEach((item) {
   NoDoItem noDoItem = NoDoItem.map(item);
   print("Db items: ${noDoItem.itemName}");
 });
}
```

I get this errors and doesn't submit something and if I'm using an Emulator it will just automatically close.

```
E/flutter (23633): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (23633): Stack Overflow
E/flutter (23633): #0      _Completer.completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:19:3)
E/flutter (23633): #1      _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1384:54)
E/flutter (23633): #2      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:20)
E/flutter (23633): #3      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:654:47)
E/flutter (23633): #4      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:675:24)
E/flutter (23633): #5      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:494:5)
E/flutter (23633): #6      _SyncCompleter._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:55:12)
E/flutter (23633): #7      _Completer.completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:27:5)
E/flutter (23633): #8      _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1384:54)
E/flutter (23633): #9      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example you were following on has errors on their **database_client.dart** file specifically causing a recursion / stack over flow exception. please update the code on **line 22** from **return db;** to **return _db;** and it should now work

```
Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db; // return db; throws a Stack Overflow Exception / recursion
    }
    _db = await initDb();
    return _db;
  }
```

Comment: This solved the problem! I actually didn't attach the database_client.dart but this problem may be similar to all the people following the tutorial. thank you for this!